# Bot Framework: Prompt and retry prompt messages appear at the same time

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, prompt

I have a prompt that I'm displaying to the user that contains a prompt message and retry prompt message, see below:

```
return await ctx.PromptAsync(CancelCurrentDialogsPrompt, new PromptOptions
{
    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Are you sure you'd like to cancel?"),
    Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(confirmationOptionsList),
    RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please select or type yes/no")
}, cancellationToken);
```

When I run the BOT in the emulator, the prompt message and the retry prompt message appear at the same time, which I'm not expecting to happen, see below:

[image: Multiple prompts]

When I enter in a incorrect option, the retry prompt shows as expected. After selecting a correct value from the list the conversation continues as expected, with no incorrect dialogs.

--- UPDATE ---

I'm calling the cancel dialog using the following code from my bot.cs class

```
await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(CancelDialog));
```

When it is being called there is nothing on the dialog stack. Here is the code in my CancelDialog.cs

```
public class CancelDialog : ComponentDialog
    {
        public readonly BotDialogSet DialogSet;

        private const string CancelWaterfallDialogs = "CancelWaterfallDialogs";
        private const string CancelCurrentDialogsPrompt = "CancelCurrentDialogsPrompt";

        public CancelDialog(BotDialogSet dialogSet) : base(nameof(CancelDialog))
        {
            DialogSet = dialogSet;

            var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                WouldYouLikeToCancel,
                CompleteUsersSelectedAction
            };

            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(CancelWaterfallDialogs, waterfallSteps));
            AddDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(CancelCurrentDialogsPrompt));
        }

        private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> WouldYouLikeToCancel (WaterfallStepContext ctx, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await ctx.PromptAsync(CancelCurrentDialogsPrompt, new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Are you sure you'd like to cancel?"),
                RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Are you sure you'd like to cancel? Please select or type yes/no")
            }, cancellationToken);
        }

        private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> CompleteUsersSelectedAction(WaterfallStepContext ctx, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if ((bool)ctx.Result)
            {
                await ctx.Parent.CancelAllDialogsAsync(cancellationToken);
                return await ctx.EndBotDialogAsync(cancellationToken);
            }

            return await ctx.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I thought I fixed your problem but i just tried your code and it actually runs normally. So can you give a bit more details of where you are trying this so i can reproduce your problem.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, your understanding is correct. But since I'm guessing you mean to ask how to solve your problem, I won't simply post "yes" as an answer.

Comment: To clarify what's happening, it sounds like you're saying the prompt "Are you sure you'd like to cancel?" and the retry prompt "Please select or type yes/no" are both being sent as separate messages on the first turn your prompt is encountered. But what happens on the turns after that? What happens if the user sends an unrecognized choice? What happens if the user's choice is recognized? Please post a screenshot of the messages in Emulator so that we can get an unambiguous impression of your conversation's flow.

Comment: You haven't explained what type of prompt this is. Is it a choice prompt or a confirm prompt? You seem to suggest that you want a yes-or-no answer, but then why are you supplying the choices in the prompt options? Confirm prompts supply the yes/no choices automatically.

Comment: There are many things that could possibly be going wrong here, but we'll need to at least see your code to figure it out. It sounds like the bot may be receiving multiple activities from the user at once, which could be caused by the channel attempting to resend messages when it thinks the message failed to send. It's also possible that your bot is responding to event activities as though they're message activities.

Comment: @KyleDelaney I've edited the post to include a screenshot and to answer some of your questions.

Thanks for pointing me in the direction of confirm prompts, this was something that I had missed. I'll implement this then see if the issue is still occurring

Comment: Thank you for posting the screenshot. I doubt using a confirm prompt will fix this problem, but we really need to see more of your code in order to figure out what's going on.

Comment: You were correct in your thinking. I have updated the post with the code from my canceldialog class

Comment: My best guess is that your bot.cs code is calling `ContinueDialogAsync` after it begins your `CancelDialog` on the same turn. Try stepping through your code to see what happens on the turn your bot receives the "cancel" message. Or if I'm going to help you I'll need to see the rest of your bot.cs code.

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- define the following:

```
 AddDialog(new TextPrompt("YNValidator", YesNoValidator);
```

-add it after:

```
  AddDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(CancelCurrentDialogsPrompt));
```

2- define YesOrNValidator:

```
private Task<bool>YorNValidator (PromptValidatorContext<string> promptContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  //Test the value... and pass true or false
    Task.FromResult(true);
 }
```

3- Next REWRITE the  WouldYouLikeToCancel

```
private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> WouldYouLikeToCancel (WaterfallStepContext ctx, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var options= new PromptOptions
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Are you sure you'd like to cancel?"),
            RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Are you sure you'd like to cancel? Please select or type yes/no")
        }, cancellationToken);
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync("YNValidator",options,cancellationToken);
    }
```